# MS Access "after insert" to replicate data accross different tables

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 Identical tables and I want any data recorded in the first table to be automatically recorded in the 2nd table using data macros. Can anyone provide me with help on how to go about it?

Comment: You would use a [CreateRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835671.aspx) data block in the After Insert data macro.

Answer (score 0):

After update, EXECUTE  an INSERT INTO sql statement to the second table